# PHP value from SQL to <!-- IF -->

Tags: php, html

What i'm looking to do is have 3 text boxes with a submit button so when i enter a username in each box that username becomes a value that i can use in this line of code:

```
<!-- IF S_USERNAME eq "{value1}" or S_USERNAME eq "{value2}" or S_USERNAME eq "{value3}" -->
```

I'm sure this is quite simple, but i can't seem to do it?

Comment: That's not php or html... is this something like a phpbb template?

Comment: @JohnB it's correct HTML. Or XML, XHTML, XSL, SVG or any superset of XML.

Comment: The value needs to be set to the sql database so it can be called on by that value tag.

Comment: Yes is is part of a phpbb3 template file, you are correct

Answer (score 1):

I do not exactly understand what you want.
But one thing first: PHP is made before thepage shows. So if you type something in a textbox you can't use PHP to do "something". You have to sent it from a form to another PHP file :)
So if you sent textbox 1 (with name="textbox1") you can retrieve it on the next page using:
`$myvar = $_GET["textbox1"]` 

Then you can use the $myvar (which is the value of 'textbox1') to use in youre SQL or PHP code :)
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks :) ok, what i want to do is create a textbox with a submit button like: '<dl> 
   <dt><label for="name1">Username 1:</label></dt> 
   <dd><input id="name1" type="text" size="20" maxlength="255" name="config[name1]" value="" /></dd> 
  </dl> '

Comment: then once i put in the username it will save that username to the database under value 'name1' or something.

Comment: so when i use this line of code from the phpbb3 template file <!-- IF S_USERNAME eq "{value1}" or S_USERNAME eq "{value2}" or S_USERNAME eq "{value3}" --> i can call that value

Comment: When you press submit on the form (with a input type=text and name="name1"), it sends this data to a "input.php". This will contain something like:<code>
    $myvar = $_GET["name1"] 
    (connect to database and all that stuff)
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('username','".$myvar."')"
    mysql_query($sql,$con)</code>

Then its in a database and you can pull it out anytime you want :)